# Why are Android Asset files in Visual Studio (Xamarin) not allowed to have accents?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, assets

I have a Visual Studio (Xamarin, Android) project with a file which has an accent character in the name:

```
 diário.png
```

This file is in the Assets folder, and marked as an Android Asset.

[image]

Unfortunately when I build the project, I get a compile error:

`C:\Users\vchel\Documents\FlatRedBallProjects\AndroidSpecialCharacter\AndroidSpecialCharacter\obj\Debug\assets\content\gumproject\dißrio.png : error : Invalid filename.  Unable to add.`

Notice that the file is diário.png in my project, but the error references it as dißrio.png.

If I rename the file to diario.png (no accent above the letter a) the project builds fine.

I know I could work around this by not using accent characters in my file but this seems like a strange restriction. Is this a known issue? Is there another way to solve this other than avoiding using accents in file names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asset naming restrictions are bound all the way back to Android `API 1`, the related build tools and `.apk` packaging (and has nothing to due with the Xamarin framework).

- Valid characters for naming resources are [a-z, _, 0–9]

  - Lowercase characters, numbers, and underscore
- Use an underscore (`_`) as a multi-name separator between "words" in your assets

  - Spaces hyphens, and periods are not allowed
- The first letter can be either _ or a small case character

  - Numbers are not allowed as the first character

Note: There used to be notes on these restrictions on the Android Developer site, but I can no longer find them as they stripped out most docs for the build tools